# Why wont Axios For Loop allow me to manipulate data in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios, google-chrome-devtools, lodash

I am building a react application using axios. I called this function useNames(allNames) which passes in an array of names that will be iterated by Axios. At first glance, it appears to work but when I console.log the data it appears to look like this....

function is run.....

```
useNames =  async (allNames) => {

        try {

            const promisesArray = [];
           await _.each((allNames), async (value) => {
                const res= await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${value}`);
                promisesArray.push(res.data);

            });

            console.log(promisesArray);


        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error('Unable to insert API data');
        }

    }

useNames(allNames);
```

output...

[image]

when opened....

[image]

The array appears to have data but when I try to manipulate it, chrome declares it as empty. I have read stack overflow responses that have similar problems but I am still unable to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing an `await` on the `_.each` part of the code. That will not work the way you expect it. `await` will wait for an async operation to complete before it moves on, however `_.each` is not an async operation even if the callback used is itself async. What you want to do is await the actual promises:

```js
useNames =  async (allNames) => {

   try {
      const promisesArray = _.map(allNames, async (value) => {
          const res= await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${value}`);
          return res.data;
      });
      const valuesArray = await Promise.all(promisesArray);
      console.log(valuesArray); // Should have resolved values
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error('Unable to insert API data');
    }
}
```

The way this works is that your async function will return a promise result which will be what the `allNames` array gets map into in this case. An array of promises can then be used with `Promise.all` which you can then await for and get all promise results.

Comment: Thanks. I've been stuck on this for hours. You're the real O.G. :)